# Why does this service call return the right count of objects in an Array, but all indexes are the same object?

Tags: angular

Working on an Angular2 service that grabs information from an API endpoint. When working with Postman to test the API call, the data is correct as so:

[image: PostMan Output]

but when the app calls the api, the contents of the array are all the same:

[image: Console Output]

I'm calling the API with the Http module within angular like so:

```
  public getPositionsById(id: number){
    let fullUrl = `records/positions/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(fullUrl)
            .map((i) => this.mapPosition(i))
            .catch((err) => {
              console.error(err);
              return err;
            });
  }
  private mapPosition(res: Response){
    let body = res.json();
    console.dir(body);
    let pos: PositionInfo[] = new Array<PositionInfo>();
    let p: PositionInfo = new PositionInfo();
    for(let b of body){
      p.IndivId = b.IndivId;
      p.positionId = b.positionId;
      p.positionCode = b.positionCode;
      p.positionTitle = b.positionTitle;
      p.districtServed = b.districtServed;
      p.areaServed = b.areaServed;
      p.reason = b.reason;
      pos.push(p);
    }
    console.dir(pos);
    return pos;
  }
```

Comment: I had the same problem because of my backend, but mine was returning from cache.

Comment: how would I go about keeping it from returning cached results?

Comment: you must check in your backend if its really returning from cache and how they treat your data.

Comment: looked at the code again, and I wasn't resetting the position object inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate the `p` object inside the for loop

```
let p: PositionInfo ;
    for(let b of body){
      p = new PositionInfo();/////  new refernce will be created every time
      p.IndivId = b.IndivId;
      p.positionId = b.positionId;
      p.positionCode = b.positionCode;
      p.positionTitle = b.positionTitle;
      p.districtServed = b.districtServed;
      p.areaServed = b.areaServed;
      p.reason = b.reason;
      pos.push(p);
    }
```

Reference is not updated

Comment: found this glitch, but never posted. Thanks @aravind